# using Iperf3 to test upload and download

Tags: linux, iperf

How to use Ipfer3 to  test upload and download speed or in other words which data of the output given below represents upload and download speed ?

**Iperf3 output**

[image: Iperf3 output]

Answer (score 7):

The iperf client initiates a connection to an iperf server, and t**he default test is the upload speed**:

```
$ iperf3 -c la.speedtest.clouvider.net -p 5209
Connecting to host la.speedtest.clouvider.net, port 5209
```

when you **use the `-R` switch, it downloads from the server**. note the 3rd line:

```
$ iperf3 -c la.speedtest.clouvider.net -p 5209 -R
Connecting to host la.speedtest.clouvider.net, port 5209
Reverse mode, remote host la.speedtest.clouvider.net is sending
```

Answer (score 1):

The default is download speed. Use option -R for upload speed.

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.xxx -R
```

This represents "Reverse Mode": run in reverse mode (server sends, client receives).

Comment: I believe this is wrong. iperf3 defaults to upload speeds from client to server. Using -R option as mentioned in the [iperf3 docs](https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php) states it the server sends and client receives thus acting as Download.

Answer (score 1):

As the other said:
iperf3 per default just tests the upload speed.

But you can perform a simultaneous upload and download by using `--bidir` on the client side:

```bash
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.xxx --bidir
```

On some newer Linux distributions, the `-d` flag is used instead:

```bash
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.xxx -d
```

This way you can get both results in a single test.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are new to iperf, I suggest you look into jperf, it is a graphing front end for iperf, that provided the options in selectable form in a GUI, that also displays the command syntax for the tests you are running to learn how to test the same direct from terminal.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/xjperf/downloads

Makes interpreting the results visually a bit nicer as well.